# Migrating to semantic logging with Castle ILogger and log4net

Tags: .net, logging, log4net, castle, etw-eventsource

What's the best way to start using the new .NET 4.5 [EventSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.eventsource.aspx) class for logging for an application that's currently using Castle's [Logging Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Logging-Facility.ashx) combined with log4net.

Initially I thought that it might be possibly to extend Castle's ILogger interface to support the richer semantic-style logging that EventSource facilitates ([Issue raised](https://github.com/castleproject/Core/issues/28)), but now I'm not so sure whether they could really work that well together.

I note that the [Semantic Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn440729%28v=pandp.60%29.aspx) provides one implementation of using EventSource, but that's of course not using ILogger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to move to semantic logging in general, not just the SLAB implementation, you might find it easier to move to [Serilog](http://serilog.net). (*Disclaimer - I started the project, though it's now well-established*).

Serilog implements the same semantic logging concepts as `EventSource` and friends, but uses the classic "ILogger"-style API you get from Castle.

```
log.Information("The cart contains {CartSize} items", cart.Count);
```

This example associates a structured property called `CartSize` with the event, just as you'd get passing a parameter to an `EventSource` method. (You can even use classic `{0}` numeric format specifiers, and still get structured events with numbered, rather than named, properties!)

Because the APIs are compatible, moving existing apps from one style of `ILogger` to another is less friction than porting everything to `EventSource`s. There are several ways to approach it, if you decide its an option I'll keep an eye out for any follow-up questions.